# Cannot access mongoDB object in array - returns undefined

Tags: mongodb, database

I have a very big problem when im trying to access objects in array in mongoDB.

First I'm finding where id key has a value of "mens" in my database collection "categories":

```
mongodb.db().collection("categories").find({id: "mens"}).toArray(function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

When i try to output the result in the console, it shows me this :

```
[ { _id: 5172d1daffdd81f3234d5f88,
    categories: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    id: 'mens',
    name: 'Mens',
    page_description: 'Men\'s range. Hard-wearing boots, jackets and clothing for unbeatable comfort day in, day out.
 headed.',
    page_title: 'Men\'s Footwear, Outerwear, Clothing & Accessories',
    parent_category_id: 'root',
    c_showInMenu: true } ]
```

But when I try to get for example name or page_title with this :

```
mongodb.db().collection("categories").find({id: "mens"}).toArray(function(err, data) {
    console.log(data.page_title);
}
```

It returns UNDEFINED ! ! !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data returned is an array, so you need to access the object in the array as `data[0].page_title` i.e.

```
mongodb.db().collection("categories").find({id: "mens"}).toArray(function(err, data) {
    console.log(data[0].page_title); // prints "Men's Footwear, Outerwear, Clothing & Accessories"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use mongoose schema. `

```
const categoriesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    categories: {type : Array},
    id: {type : String},
    name: {type : String},
    page_description: {type : String},
    page_title: {type : String},
    parent_category_id: {type : String},
    c_showInMenu: {type : Boolean}  });
const dataTahunAjaran = mongoose.models.categories || mongoose.model('categories', categoriesSchema);
```

and then you can acces `page_title:` even object inside object inside object even very deep inside
`